# Regex to replace <a> href and <img> alt in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I'm trying to do a search and replace across a lot of files and I need to format the following HTML.

```
<a href="http://www.XXXXXXXXX.com target=_blank">
<img alt="XXXXXXXXX" src=http://domain.org/files/image.gif" />
</a>
```

I need regex for the XXXXXXX parts.  Basically find all combinations of the domains used and all combinations of the alt words used.

Some domains have 1 `-` (dash) and others have 2 `-` (dashes) in them while the rest do not.  Some alt images are 2 words while others are 3.  There are no numbers in the domain or alt tags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing with pencil&paper on in a specific programming language? In either case, regex + html are not close friends.

Comment: The obligatory reference to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I'm going to use it in notepad++.  Will it give me issues?

Comment: And you need to replace it with what exactly? I mean, do you need to capture these 'XXXXX' or not?

Comment: Are the missing quotes typo? or is it the real string you have to change?

Comment: Hmm - I'm not sure what you plan to replace...  In any case you should use an xml processor such as sax or xslt, not regex.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
a href="http://www\..+\.com\ +target
```

with

```
a href="http://www.NEWVALUE.com target
```

Replace:

```
img alt="[^"]+"\ +src=
```

with

```
img alt="NEWVALUE" src=
```